# How can I run a unit test in a browser environment?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, headless, ava, google-chrome-headless

I am writing a test for some code that manipulates the DOM, and I wanted to run it in a browser environment and I don't know how.

I wrote a mockup test using the testing library [AVA](https://github.com/avajs/ava), for my small library [promisify-dom-selector](https://github.com/marcofugaro/promisify-dom-selector):

```
const test = require('ava')
const promisifyDOMSelector = require('index.js')

test('pGetElementById works', t => {
  const pGetElementById = promisifyDOMSelector(document.getElementById)

  pGetElementById('load-later')
    .then((el) => {
      t.deepEqual(el, document.getElementById('load-later'))
    })

  const testEl = document.createElement('div')
  testEl.id = 'load-later'
  document.body.appendChild(testEl)
})
```

and wanted to run it in [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/headless-karma-mocha-chai).

I've tried setting up Karma with the ava plugin [karma-ava](https://github.com/avajs/karma-ava) but it doesn't even work, here is the error message:

[image]

I wouldn't go with the Karma route if possible, but I don't know of any other way! What can I do?

Comment: look into casperjs. casper is a wrapper for phantomjs and does all the things you're after.

Comment: I got just the article for you: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/headless-karma-mocha-chai. Good luck

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy yeah I tried going the way of that article and using karma, but it didn't work out with ava

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to *actually* test in a browser then the [browser testing](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/recipes/browser-testing.md) recipe includes some helpful pointers.

https://github.com/avajs/karma-ava hasn't seen any work in over a year, so I'm not surprised if that doesn't work.

If you do need to run your code in an actual browser I'd use http://www.nightmarejs.org/ or something with an HTML document you can control from AVA in order to test your library.

Comment: Yes I knew about nightmare.js, but wanted to use HeadlessChrome because is fresher. Also Chromeless has the same api of nightmare.js

Answer (score 1):

Cypress has recently released [Cypress Component Testing](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2021/04/06/cypress-component-testing-react/). This supports major frameworks like React and Vue. The tests will run in headless browser instead of jsdom in node env.